# Why does this table render differently between Chrome and Firefox?

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I have a table that seems to be rendering differently between Chrome and Firefox. The Chrome output is correct, and the Firefox output isn't.

```css
body {
  background-color: #e1e1e1;
  word-wrap: break-word
}

#about-table {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.panel {
  background-color: #f5f5f6;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  color: #1c1c1c;
  margin: 16px;
  padding: 32px;
  text-align: center;
}

.person {
  display: inline;
}

.portrait {
  width: 100%;
}

.portrait-container {
  max-width: 256px;
  width: 50%;
}

.portrait-label {
  font-weight: 600;
  width: 128px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/8.0.0/normalize.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/lib/index2.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <div class="panel">
    <table id="about-table">
      <tr class="person">
        <td class="portrait-container"><img class="portrait" src="/img/head-julian.jpg" /></td>
        <td class="portrait-label">Person 1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="person">
        <td class="portrait-container"><img class="portrait" src="/img/head-simon.jpg" /></td>
        <td class="portrait-label">Person 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="person">
        <td class="portrait-container"><img class="portrait" src="/img/head-jacob.jpg" /></td>
        <td class="portrait-label">Person 3</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
```

On Firefox (and Edge), the third item in the table always gets put on its own line, regardless of how much horizontal space there is.

Comment: What makes you think Chrome is correct here?

Comment: What versions of both browsers are you using? Most of your prefixed properties don't need them for the current versions of each browser

Comment: @PoulBak It may not be the correct behavior, but its the behavior I intended.

Comment: @j08691 I'm using the latest version of both browsers. The prefixed properties aren't relevant to the question, so I'll remove it.

Comment: What I see is 3 'identical' table rows. Why should the third behave differently than the other two?

Comment: That width of `.portrait-container`. What do you think that's 50% of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To apply `display: inline;` to a table row (via class `.person`) doesn't really make sense - either you use DIVs and apply according CSS to them or you use a "real" table (i.e. HTML table elements like `table`, tr`and`td`, as it would be without that CSS rule).

Everything else, i.e. every "mixture" of default table layout properties and different CSS `display` definitions just depends on the browser's tolerance/interpretation which you are experiencing. But I doubt that this (i.e. the `tr` tags and their `display: inline` definition) is a valid combination of "native" HTML layout properties and CSS.

I would for example use flexbox properties on DIVs instead of all those not-real-table-elements as shown below:

```css
body {
  background-color: #e1e1e1;
  word-wrap: break-word
}

#about-table {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;

}

.panel {
  background-color: #f5f5f6;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  color: #1c1c1c;
  margin: 16px;
  padding: 32px;
  text-align: center;
}

.person {
  display: flex;
  width: 30%;
  align-items: center;
}

.portrait {
  width: 100%;
}

.portrait-container {
  max-width: 256px;
  width: 50%;
}

.portrait-label {
  font-weight: 600;
  width: 128px;
}
```

```html
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/8.0.0/normalize.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/lib/index2.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <div class="panel">
    <div id="about-table">
      <div class="person">
        <div class="portrait-container"><img class="portrait" src="/img/head-julian.jpg" /></div>
        <div class="portrait-label">Person 1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="person">
        <div class="portrait-container"><img class="portrait" src="/img/head-simon.jpg" /></div>
        <div class="portrait-label">Person 2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="person">
        <div class="portrait-container"><img class="portrait" src="/img/head-jacob.jpg" /></div>
        <div class="portrait-label">Person 3</div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```